# Any ip and local ip binding?

Tags: c++, sockets, tcp, udp, bind

I'm working on a network platform that creates a basic I/O interface for make something fast/easy. I need to understand this, what is the main differences between binding any ip or local ip to socket? Why I need to bind local ip, why I need to bind any ip? Simple but important question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Binding a server socket to a local ip instead of to 0.0.0.0 can act like a poor man's firewall if you want to have a server that is not open to the entire world, but only to a specific group.

For example: 
 - You can bind a socket to the local ip if you want it to be used a way for different processes in the same machine to communicate.
 - You can bind a socket to an ip if you want all access to it to occur through some external load balancer.

Comment: "open to the entire world". Namely if I want to make a online system, I should (or must, IDK) bind ANY ip?

Comment: Yes, it is recommended that you bind to 0.0.0.0

Comment: Wait, I want to make sure, we are talking about a socket that belongs to a server, and not to a client, right?

Comment: Yes. That's server-side.

Comment: Ok, then what I said is correct, just wanted to be 100% sure.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that a TCP connection is made up of four things: Source address, source port number, destination address and destination port number.

When e.g. a server program binds a socket to a local address, two of those things are provided, and allows clients to connect to a well know destination.

When you bind to any address, it doesn't actually bind to *any* address, it just creates the binding for all local addresses. (For hosts that have multiple interfaces, which all hosts have.)

Comment: When I need to use ANY ip?

Comment: @PiLaWYeR When you want to e.g. accept connections on all local interfaces.

Comment: "all **_local_** interfaces". If I want world-wide (online network-internet). What I should use?

Comment: @PiLaWYeR Uhm, you can't? If you're server machine is reachable from the general Internet, then all you have to do is bind to the **local** interface that has that Internet connection. It will allow any host on the Internet to connect to your system.

Comment: It is customary to use INADDR_ANY unless you have a specific reason not to, rather than having to decide which 'local interface has the Internet connection'.